# Having an issue with iframe on IE8 and IE9

Tags: html

I have a `<href>` link in the html code which works well when not put inside the `<iframe>` tag and the same link gives issue when put inside the `<iframe>`

Below is the code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://localhost/TestingLink.htm"></iframe>
```

Code for TestingLink.htm:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Click me</a>
```

Comment: This is because Google doesn't allow their site to be loaded inside an iFrame.

Answer (score 2):

It's due to Google adding `DENY` to the `X-Frame-Options` header. Meaning you cannot embed that site in an iframe.

> DENY:    The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the
>   site attempting to do so.

And this is the error you will see when you debug the page with the iframe on:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.co.uk/ does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

Read more about X-Frame-Options here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options